# Need to Hidden text in file input and resize the browser button in IE

Tags: javascript, php, html

In my project I have file input button, for that i need to remove the file text box and need to set some background for browse button.

[image]

Kindly give me idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nicely styled file upload**

Programmatically trigger a click

CODE

```
$('img#mytrigger').on('click', function () {
  $('#fileupload-example-1').trigger('click');
});
```

Provide a label for the input field

CODE

```
<input type="file" id="fileupload-example-4"/>
<label id="fileupload-example-4-label" for="fileupload-example-4">Click me</label>
```

CSS

```
#fileupload-example-4 {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

#fileupload-example-4-label {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

jQuery is required for this method. Include the following line in code too.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Ref: [link](http://damien.antipa.at/blog/2014/02/26/how-to-style-a-html-file-input/)

Comment: Thanks for you idea. I try this technique before, I did on some action in on change event for file input so if i trigger click event for file input in jquery means the onchange event is not working fine in IE.

Answer (score 0):

try this technique..

```
echo "<div>\n";
    echo "<div style=\"width:80px;position:absolute;\">Browse</div >\n";
    echo "<input type=\"file\" style=\"width:80px;position:absolute;opacity:0;\" />\n";
echo "</div>\n";
```